# How to add watermark in PDF using Apache PDFBox Overlay

Tags: java, overlay, pdfbox, watermark, pdfbox-layout

I am trying to add watermark to PDF. I am taking following two files as inputs:

1. Original PDF file: To which needs to be added.
2. Watermark PDF File: It is one page PDF which only contains watermark.

I am trying to combine those files in PDFBox `Overlay` to generate new document containing watermark in it.

```
PDDocument watermarkDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));
//Assuming your empty document with watermark image in it.

        PDDocument realDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("..."));

        Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
        overlay.setInputPDF(realDoc);
        overlay.setDefaultOverlayPDF(watermarkDoc);
        PDDocument document = overlay.overlay(new HashMap<Integer, String>());
        document.save("..."));
```

But when I try to open newly generated document in acrobat, though the watermark is displayed in the file, but Acrobat is not able to detect it. That is I am not able to perform any operation like update or delete watermark.

Comment: If I interchange Input pdf and default overlay pdf then it is working, i.e.,  
overlay.setInputPDF(watermarkDoc);
overlay.setDefaultOverlayPDF(realDoc);
Then I am able to edit watermark through acrobat. But the issue here is it will only work in 1 page PDF. for multiple pages PDF, it will not work.

Comment: *"But when I try to open newly generated document in acrobat, though the watermark is displayed in the file, but Acrobat is not able to detect it."* - Thus, your problem is not "How to add watermark in PDF using Apache PDFBox Overlay" but "How to add watermark in PDF using Apache PDFBox Overlay in a way that the functions of a specific different software, Adobe Acrobat, also handle as watermarks". This is a completely different matter as there are myriads of ways to apply watermarks but Adobe only recognized a very few of them.

Comment: Please share example PDFs to illustrate the issue.